# Convert 7-speed cassette to 4 speeds

Tags: cassette

I have a 12t-28t Shimano HG cassette.  I only use cogs 12t, 14t, 16t, and 18t.  Can I remove the others and use a spacer or something in their place?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  What would be the point of removing the other cogs?  I mean, I don't see a reason that it would be impossible, but why?

Comment: @DavidW I suspect its for weight savings.  but I've never felt that carrying a rare-used gear is a waste of mass.   I've certainly missed them when not there - both at the big and small ends of the cassette.

Comment: @DavidW Simplicity.  Function.  I only want what I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe**

If you removed half the cogs, the remaining ones would be closer together and effectively have a "steeper" angle required.

The rear mech will move in a diagonal line along the cassette.

So either the upper jockey wheel will be too close and hit the big cog, or too far away from the small cogs and have minimal tooth engagement.

---

If you remove the biggest cogs only, (say 28, 24, and 21?) then the four smaller cogs could totally sit at the end of the cassette with a chunky metal spacer underneath.  This could save some weight, but you'd have to adjust your limit stop to prevent the bike going over the top from 18T.

The spacer could be aluminium pipe but has to be cut to a precise length, so that the cassette's lockring still screws in place with enough threads to engage and retain itself.  You should get a series of clicks as the lockring seats down and the remaining cogs should not move on the freehub's splines.

Also, you'll regret it come the next big headwind ride or ride up a climb.

So yes its possible, but most people want more gears not fewer.

---

Next time you replace your cassette, try and get a 11-18 or 12-19 corncob with 7 gears and see if that suits you better.   Having sing-tooth steps gives you more options while riding to optimise your cadence for comfort.

Comment: Who makes those corncobs?  I'm on a 1992 MTB.  The hub is a Shimano too.

Comment: @Criggie OP is talking about keeping the smallest 4 cogs with no gaps.  (IIRC the 3 being removed would be 21, 24, 28.)

Comment: @DavidW yep that's the second part of the answer.

Comment: @UngarLinski based on https://www.sheldonbrown.com/k7-7.shtml   you'd want the old "ab" 7 speed shimano cassette which is no longer available, but went from 11-15,17,19.  Or you could have CS‑HG50 L which is 12-15, 17,19, 21.   To get a true corncob you would buy a CS‑HG50 L and either a B or an E and drill out the rivets, then restack the cogs, with some leftovers.   Good luck finding exactly what you want.

Comment: 12t, 14t, 16t, and 18t looks like these should be adjacent.

Comment: Exactly. @DavidW

Comment: Never tried it, but I doubt the limit stop would go in that far.  What would happened if you dropped the derailleur off the 18 - bend metal or just a pain to put it back on?

Comment: @mattnz well if OP started with a 12-28 and removed the three biggest cogs, there'd be enough space between the 18 and the spokes for three chains to lie side by side.  The chain would simply rattle around there and drag over the spacer covering the freehub's splines.   It might take a hand to get it back or simply shifting carefully might get there too.